# How to associate waypoints with their geocache when loaded from a GPX file

Tags: xml, gpx, geocaching

I am writing an application that reads in pocket queries from Geocaching.com and displays them on a map. I already have it parsing the gpx and wpts.gpx files. I want to be able to list the associated waypoints under their geocache, but I am at a loss as to how to link the waypoints with their geocaches as there seems to be no reference in either file to the other. Is there something I am missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the suffixes are the same for the Waypoint ID and just the prefix (the first two letters) change.  I agree, it's not well designed.